# Merge [spoof] and [spoofing]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[spoofing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/spoofing) - 21 questions tagged.

[spoof](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/spoof) - 6 questions tagged.

They're obviously identical. Can we merge them (I guess [spoof](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/spoof) into [spoofing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/spoofing)?) and synonymize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a good idea to me. I'd go ahead with merge+synonymize.